# Translation of an article by Wolfgang Schmidt on normality for real numbers in different bases.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, nt.number-theory, reference-request

I would greatly appreciate a pointer to a translation from German into English of the article by Wolfgang Schmidt, Über die Normalität von Zahlen zu verschiedenen Basen, from Acta Arithmetica VII, 1962.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect that such a translation exist? You are probably better off using some OCR/translate app.

Comment: I vote to close this "as not a real question". As Felipe Voloch says chances are high this simply does not exist. In particular, this state of affairs shows that it would be a much better question, were there some indication *why* such a translation would be needed. Depending on this people could perhaps suggest alternative sources.    

Comment: I now have an English translation of the Schmidt article.  So the question is now moot.

Comment: @TheodoreSlaman: where did you find it ? I just asked Wolfgang Schmidt about it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: My colleague Mariya Soskova and I worked up a translation ourselves.